# How can I check sent emails from my Android application? Or intent upon completion (regardless of email sent)?

Tags: java, android, email, android-activity

I want to check for email completion, then start another activity.

So my question is really how do I check `i` for completion?

```
EDIT:
```

**Or is there a way to close the intent upon completion (regardless of email sent) and check for that event?**

I'm using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable way to determine whether your email was sent.

Theoretically you can use `startActivityForResult()`, but depending on the email client you will get incorrect results. GMail for example always returns `RESULT_CANCELED`, no matter if you send the mail or cancel (at least for me), while Google Drive will respond correctly with `RESULT_OK` if the email was stored in Drive, or `RESULT_CANCELED` if not.

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_MAIL = 1000;

private void startMailIntent(){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."), REQUEST_CODE_MAIL);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MAIL){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // Mail was sent.
        } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Sending was cancelled.
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Or is there a way to close the intent upon completion (regardless of email sent) and check for that event?

Comment: `onActivityResult` should always be called with `REQUEST_CODE_MAIL` if the email intent was finished (with email sent or not). You can perform any action in there (if I understand you correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you can. There's no result passback from sending the data out to an email client.